# Javascript: Filter variables that have been attached to global scope?

Tags: javascript, browser, scope, window, global

Is it possible to find variables that have been attached to the window scope in a browser? Not pre-existing variables, but ones that have been attached by me.

Doing console.log(window) gives a long list of variables available, but I only want to see what has been attached by me.

Answer (score 1):

Well we can pull out any functions that have `"[native function]"` since those are... native. The following snippet will create an array `non_natives` of function names that were not pre-existing.

```
var non_natives = [];

for ( fin in window ) {
  if ( typeof(window[fin]) === "function" && window[ fin ].toString().indexOf("[native code]") === -1 ) {
    non_natives.push( fin );
  }
}
```

If you copy and paste that in your web console, you should be able to view the `non_natives` array.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce output to only variables , Try this

```
Object.keys(window)
```